# Dynamically update 'max' validation in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, validation, min

**Edit: Massively simplified to get to the core of the problem**

In Angular (v1.2.22) validation, if the value of `max` depends on another value, and that value updates, the validation state does not automatically update.

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]).
controller('TestCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.partWidth = 10;
});
```

HTML:

```
<form name="itemForm">
  <label for="partWidth">Part width</label>
  <input id="partWidth" name="partWidth" min="10" max="180"  ng-model="partWidth" placeholder="mm" required type="number">

  <label for="cutterwidth">Cutter width</label>
  <input id="cutterwidth" name="cutterwidth" min="10" max="{{ partWidth }}"  ng-model="cutterwidth" placeholder="mm" required type="number">
</form>
```

Updated Plunker
http://plnkr.co/edit/lNemYyFrHF9gyRgY8KIT

The `ng-invalid` class is not removed unless the `cutterwidth` itself is edited.

a) Is this a bug?

b) Is there a workaround? (e.g. force validation to run, somehow trigger the input event etc)

Comment: Interestingly, if you watch at the `max=""` attribute of `cutterwidth` in the rendered page it DOES update live as the value of partwidth is changed. However Angular only removes the `ng-invalid` class when the cutterwidth itself is edited, this is not triggered when the value of `max` changes. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a) I think it's [this bug](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2404).

b) My workaround, after much epic battling, was to avoid using the native `max` attribute entirely, and to build a custom directive instead.

I'm exposing the `ngAppMax` attribute to the scope, and passing in `ngModel` using the `=`. I don't fully understand this but it works.

I'm then comparing the two values and using `$setValidity` on the model (named 'ctrl').

[Here's a working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/PZVV2kWjDv5Wv3hNARKV?p=preview), or see below:

**HTML**

```
<form name="itemForm">
  <input name="partWidth" min="10" max="300" ng-model="partWidth" placeholder="mm" required type="number">
  <input name="cutterwidth" min="10" ng-app-max="{{ partWidth }}" ng-model="cutterWidth" placeholder="mm" required type="number">
</form>
```

**JS**

```
angular.module('app',[]).
controller('TestCtrl', function($scope){}).
directive('ngAppMax', function(){
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    scope: {
      ngAppMax: '@',
      ngModel: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl){

      scope.$watch('ngAppMax', function(newVal){
        validate(scope.ngModel, newVal, ctrl);
      });

      scope.$watch('ngModel', function(val){
        validate(val, scope.ngAppMax);
      });

      function validate(thisVal, maxVal){
        if(thisVal > maxVal){
          ctrl.$setValidity('range', false);
        } else {
          ctrl.$setValidity('range', true);
        }
      }

    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you have missed out a little detail in the logic.

For your PartWidth, what you need to do is to check whether the user has input anything below 10, or anything below the `cutterwidth`. Thus, a `getMax` function should do the trick.

```
    <input id="width" name="width" min="{{ getMax(10, cutterwidth) }}" max="180"   ng-model="width"    placeholder="mm" required type="number">
```

The `getMax` function is pretty straightforward. Just inverse the `getMin` function.

Here is the [working plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/0SMx9cJo28ibDs106qkt?p=preview)

Comment: I could add that, but partWidth needs no dependency on the cutter width, and this doesn't actually solve the problem. Perhaps I didn't explain it well enough.

Comment: Okay, I re-read your question. Sorry for the wrong answer. If I am able to solve it I will update the answer.

Comment: I've completely rewritten it as a simplified scenario. Hopefully clearer now.